# regarding h264_qsv encoding speed in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, intel, h.264

As we know, now ffmpeg supports intel hardware encoding(h264 qsv).
But it doesn't support "ultra fast", is there any settings to improve the encoding speed?

```
m_encoder = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv");
if(m_encoder == nullptr){
    LOG(ERROR)<<"Find H264 Encoder failed";
    return false;
}
m_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_encoder);
m_ctx->bit_rate = bitrate_kbps*1024;
m_ctx->width = m_width;
m_ctx->height = m_height;
m_ctx->time_base = { 1, (int)fps };
m_ctx->qmin = 10;
m_ctx->qmax = 35;
m_ctx->gop_size = fps;
m_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
m_ctx->has_b_frames = false;

m_ctx->codec_id = m_encoder->id;
m_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
m_ctx->pix_fmt = m_h264InputFormat;

AVDictionary *param = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&param, "look_ahead", "0", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "look_ahead_depth", "8", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "preset", "veryfast", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);

int ret = avcodec_open2(m_ctx, m_encoder, &param);
```

Comment: Probably not much else you can do. (Also, I do not believe this encoder supports `-tune`). Best thing you can do to increase encoding fps is perform multiple encodings at the same time. You can see a list of private options for this encoder with `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_qsv`

Comment: yes, you are right. qsv doesn't support tune, I tried other settings, but  nothing happen. I can't believe the hardware encoding performance is lower than x264.